# Index a column encrypted with pkg_crypto

Tags: performance, oracle, encryption, oracle10g

I'm working on a project that uses pkg_crypto to protect users' personal information.  There are several thousand rows (which is expected to grow to maybe several tens of thousands), and whenever I use a `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` clause in a query, the whole table is decrypted before the results are returned.  This takes several seconds for a single query, which is usable for development but will probably not be very good for the release.

Is there a way to create an index that will work on the encrypted columns without compromising security?

The inserts and selects look something like this (with iBatis):

**insert:**

```
INSERT INTO "USER_TABLE" 
(
"ID"
,"LOGIN"
,"PASSWORD"
,"NAME"
,"EMAIL"
)
VALUES
(
user_table_seq.nextval, 
#login#
,#password#
,pkg_crypto.encrypt(#name#, 'key')
,pkg_crypto.encrypt(#email#, 'key') 
)
```

**select:**

```
SELECT 
"ID"
,"LOGIN"
,"PASSWORD"
,pkg_crypto.decrypt("NAME", 'key') NAME
,pkg_crypto.decrypt("EMAIL", 'key')  EMAIL
FROM "USER_TABLE"
WHERE pkg_crypto.decrypt("NAME", 'key') LIKE #name# || '%'
AND pkg_crypto.decrypt("EMAIL", 'key') LIKE '%' || #email#
```

I'll preemptively put out there that the password is hashed by the servlet before being passed to the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substantially, the answer is **No**.

When each value is encrypted, it has a random IV (initialization vector) chosen to go with it.  And this means that you cannot predict what is going into the index.  If you re-encrypt the value (even with the same key), you will get a different result.  Therefore, you cannot meaningfully use an index on the encrypted value because you cannot reproduce the encryption for the value you're searching for.  The index would, in any case, only be useful for equality searches.  The data would be in a random sequence.

You might do better with a hash value stored (as well as the encrypted value).  If you hash the names with a known algorithm, then you can reproduce the hash value on demand and find the rows that match.  But simply knowing the hash won't allow you (or an intruder) to determine the value that was hashed except through pre-computed 'rainbow tables'.

So, you cannot meaningfully index encrypted columns - not even for uniqueness (since the same value would be encrypted different ways by virtue of the random IV).

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to use `PKG_CRYPTO` to encrypt the data (which, I'm assuming, is something you wrote that calls either `DBMS_CRYPTO` or `DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT`?  Oracle has a feature called [transparent data encryption (TDE)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/advanced-security/index-099011.html) (though this is an extra cost option) that would allow you to have Oracle transparently encrypt the data on disk, decrypt it when it's read from disk, and then use this sort of `LIKE` predicate on your data.

Comment: I.. just assumed it was a commonly used library.  It was included in the prototype I was given.

Comment: Also, I believe the specs called for an encryption scheme that would protect information even if an attacker can execute queries on the db.